# How to use MvvmCross plugins in Android without compiling DLL?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a problem using my own MvvmCross plugins in an Android project, because the `PluginLoader` seems to expect a `.Droid.dll` of the exact namespace it is in.

Say I have three projects with this folder and namespace structure:

```
MyApp.Core:
    Plugins/Settings/ISettings.cs
    Plugins/Settings/PluginLoader.cs
MyApp.Droid:
    Plugins/Settings/Settings.cs
    Plugins/Settings/Plugin.cs
    Bootstrap/SettingsPluginBootstrap.cs
MyApp.Touch:
    Plugins/Settings/Settings.cs
    Plugins/Settings/Plugin.cs
    Bootstrap/SettingsPluginBootstrap.cs
```

The iOS project works just as expected, and finds the plugin without problem.

The Droid project on the other hand, fails with an exception: `Could not load file or assembly 'MyApp.Plugins.Settings.Droid.dll' or one of its dependencies.`

If I change the namespace of the `PluginLoader` from `MyApp.Core.Plugins.Settings` to simply `MyApp`, the plugin works; I guess it looks for the `MyApp.dll` and finds it. However, if I have multiple plugins in my app, they should each have their own namespace, they can't all be in the `MyApp` namespace.

Currently the only workaround I have found is to create a separate project for each plugin I create, though this feels a bit unnecessary.

Why does the `PluginLoader` insist on looking for the `<PluginLoader namespace>.Droid.dll` file on Android, when the `PluginLoader` on iOS finds the plugin without any problem?

Comment: Thanks for an interesting question - I think the space you are exploring is slightly different (but with shared areas) to the area where plugins are currently used. I quite like the idea of the core project somehow being able to define "contracts" for the ui project though - so have logged this as an idea - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/496

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MvvmCross plugins are designed to work as an assembly based layer on top of IoC.

By using a shared pattern for namespaces and assemblies, along with a couple of helper classes (Plugin and PluginLoader), plugins provide a way to share and reuse portable native code components.

The reason why iOS (and Mac) use a slightly different plugin loading scheme is because the MonoTouch's AoT compiler will not allow dynamic `Assembly.Load` loading.

Because of this iOS has to use a different type of `PluginManager` and a different type of `Bootstrap` class to the other platforms. There's a bit more info on this in "How plugins are loaded" in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#how-plugins-are-loaded

---

If you wanted to add the `Loader` type plugin registry to Android as well as iOS, then I think you could do this in a custom `PluginManager` class and could then create this during Setup using an override of `protected override IMvxPluginManager CreatePluginManager()`.

Something like:

```
public class MyPluginManager : MvxFilePluginManager, IMvxLoaderPluginManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<IMvxPlugin>> _finders = new Dictionary<string, Func<IMvxPlugin>>();

    public MyPluginManager(string platformDllPostfix, string assemblyExtension = "") : base(platformDllPostfix, assemblyExtension)
    {
    }

    public IDictionary<string, Func<IMvxPlugin>> Finders
    {
        get { return _finders; }
    }

    protected override IMvxPlugin FindPlugin(Type toLoad)
    {
        var pluginName = toLoad.Namespace;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pluginName))
        {
            throw new MvxException("Invalid plugin type {0}", toLoad);
        }

        Func<IMvxPlugin> finder;
        if (_finders.TryGetValue(pluginName, out finder))
        {
            return finder();
        }

        return base.FindPlugin(toLoad);
    }
}
```

initialised in your Setup using:

```
    protected override IMvxPluginManager CreatePluginManager()
    {
        return new MyPluginManager(".Droid", ".dll");
    }
```

you would then need to ensure that your `loader` based plugins uses bootstrap classes based off of `MvxLoaderPluginBootstrapAction` and not `MvxPluginBootstrapAction`

---

As another alternative, if you are not interested in reusing your plugins individually - if you would rather not ship lots of individual plugin assemblies - then you could put all your interfaces and implementations into one single assembly - and they could then share a single `Bootstrap`, `Plugin` and `PluginLoader` between them.

---

As a final alternative, for your custom needs, you can always consider using your own custom bootstrap classes - the standard `Setup` will create and `Run` any constructable class in your UI assembly which implements `IMvxBootstrapAction` - so you could replace `SettingsPluginBootstrap` with some custom `Run` action that suits your apps needs.

```
public class SettingsBootstrapAction
    : IMvxBootstrapAction
{
    public void Run()
    {
        // my stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a lot of viable alternatives, I think I understand plugins better now. Currently I am overriding `InitializePlatformServices` in `Setup.cs` and registering the plugins with e.g. `Mvx.ConstructAndRegisterSingleton<ISettings, Settings>()`, while keeping the default plugin behaviour for iOS, but it feels a bit messy; mixing plugin pattern and IoC container.